# How to build an Ajax search bar with multiple keywords?

Tags: javascript, mysql, ajax, database

I tried to build an ajax search bar. It works fine with a single keyword but I can't manage to make it work with 2 keywords... 
I was thinking about parsing the data in the input field but my knowledge is limited and I didn't manage to find the solution. 
Any ideas?

In my main.js I get the data from the input like this:

```
var kwVal = $(this).val();
if (kwVal.length < 3){
    $(".clothes-container").html("");
}
else {

    $.ajax({
        "url": "ajax/getclothes.php",
        "type": "GET",
        "data": {
            "kw": kwVal 
        }
    })
```

And this is my sql request

```
    $sql = "SELECT title, description, picture
    FROM outfit 
    WHERE type LIKE :keyword OR
          color LIKE :keyword OR
          brand LIKE :keyword OR
          material LIKE :keyword";
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: How should Your system handle more keywords? Should it find items that contain all the words or just any single word?

Comment: How about `$sql = "SELECT title, description, picture
    FROM outfit 
    WHERE type LIKE '%$input%' OR
          color LIKE '%$input%' OR
          brand LIKE '%$input%' OR
          material LIKE '%$input%'";`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? Of course, all the SQL literals and strings must be properly escaped (especially the `$keyword`).

```
// keywords extracted from user's input
$keywords = array('blue', 'jeans');

// columns, that You want to match against
$columns = array('type', 'color', 'brand', 'material');

// we build the condition for each keyword
$word_conditions = array();
foreach ($keywords as $keyword) {

    $conditions = array();
    foreach ($columns as $column)
        $conditions[] = $column.' LIKE \'%'.$keyword.'%\'';

    $word_conditions[] = '('.implode(' OR ', $conditions).')';
}

// we build the query, that requires every item to have all the keywords
$query = 'SELECT * FROM ... WHERE '.implode(' AND ', $word_conditions);
```

Comment: Thanks but I still didn't manage to make it work... It doesn't take into consideration the second keyword... If I search black dress it will output everything which is black... Maybe there is an error with my database but I just created a simple database where every columns are on the same table. so..I will keep on trying.

Comment: Would You paste final SQL query that it produced for "black", "dress", please?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your keywords are saperated by 'Space' like "ABC DEF GEH".

than on server you can do is,

```
$keywords = explode(" ", $_POST['data']); //Make it array;
$string = implode(",", $keywords);

$sql = "SELECT title, description, picture
    FROM outfit 
    WHERE type in (".$string.") OR
          color in (".$string.") OR
          brand in (".$string.") OR
          material in (".$string.")";
```

Comment: This looks dangerously. http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=javascript%20sql%20injection%20parameterized https://xkcd.com/327/